# Font wont centre indiv on mobile

Tags: javascript

Currently the script for a mobile responsive site doesnt work initially but onced refreshed or switched to landscape the script works and centers the text inside the div. I was having trouble placing the script in Jsfiddle. I have a placed a link to the live site, needs to be resized to mobile size. Problem is on the index (home page) http://www.matrix-scm.com

Below is the the javascript used:

```
//that one jquery plugin - ignore
$(function( $ ){

    $.fn.flexVerticalCenter = function( onAttribute ) {

        return this.each(function(){
            var $this       = $(this);              // store the object
            var attribute   = onAttribute || 'margin-top'; // the attribute to put the calculated value on

            // recalculate the distance to the top of the element to keep it centered
            var resizer = function () {
                // get parent height minus own height and devide by 2
                $this.css(
                    attribute, ( ( $this.parent().height() - $this.height() ) / 2 )
                );
            };

            // Call once to set.
            resizer();

            // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default. 
            $(window).resize(resizer);

            // Apply a load event to images within the element so it fires again after an image is loaded
            $this.find('img').load(resizer);

        });

    };

})( jQuery );

//actually using it


$('span.typeone').flexVerticalCenter();

$('span.typetwo').flexVerticalCenter();

$('span.typethree').flexVerticalCenter();

$('span.typefour').flexVerticalCenter();
```

Unfortunalty I'm new to the site so I dont have enough reputation to post images of the non working mobile site. If you check it in google chrome you can resize and refesh the index page to see the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Many thanks

Dom

Comment: Seems ok to me... Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When in google chrome it wont work until refreshed or resized on the desktop. On mobile safari it only works after being refreshed but will then work after you have been on that page. On the Ipad it doesnt work at all.

Comment: Errors still present on mobile/Ipad device when the site is loaded 1st time. Problem fixes itself when switched to landscape view on chrome, safari, ie and firefox. Problem doesn’t reappear apart from on chrome, when problem reappears when browser refreshed. Any help would be appreciated.